# Snow tires for H Plus Son SL42?

Tags: tire, rims, winter, fixed-gear

I'm riding fixed gear with H Plus Son SL42 rims and Schwalbe Lugano.

I'm thinking about changing my tires to be able to ride in snow/wet roads, but in the H Plus Son site I don't see the maximum size tire that I can fit in the rim.

Given the following diagram, what's the maximum tire that could fit?

I've seen some Schwalbe that look good, but they are 700x30C and 700x33C...

[image]

Comment: Are you talking studded snow tires?

Comment: I didn't think about it, do you think it makes sense to get those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complete knowledge base on fitting tires for different rim-sizes, see here: http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html
and scroll down to 'Width Considerations'.
30 or 33mm tires will fit your rims but they'll probably need a lot of pressure which might just be counter-productive on snow. On the other hand you should consider another possible issue: 30 or 33mm tires might not fit into the front fork or between the rear stays.
If they do, you might want to buy a second pair of wider wheels and use the wider tires on these. It will keep your 'Summer' wheels nice and shiny.

Comment: Why would they need a lot of pressure? On even ground with mud or snow you could probably ride them down to 2bar or so.

Comment: Big tyres on narrow rims need higher pressure to keep their shape and be ridable. At low pressure they are likely to move sideways when cornering. And the risk of pinch flats increases. On a wider rim they remain more easily seated at low pressure and the pinching risk is smaller.

Comment: I’ve only had the problem with the tire buckling sidewards at less than 2 bar with 30mm tires (Michelin Mud2) on 15mm rims. Not really a practical usecase. I’ve never quite understood the argument about pinching. There should always be tire between rims and ground, so there’ll always be pinching once you bottom out. I do understand that wide rims will slightly increase tire width.

Answer (score 1):

So guessing from the figure they have something like 17mm width on the inside. A bit more than twice the (interior) width is usually okay for tires. So you could safely go up to ~35mm if your frame and brakes have enough clearance.

You are probably considering the Schwalbe Racing Ralph, which are not bad, but if you have the money I’d recommend Michelin Mud2.

Comment: Mud2 look pretty f*cking good. I'll probably go for those. Now I just need a new frame and a disk fork. Mid term project, we will see : ) Many thanks for the comment!